# How to change shortcut for switching languages to ctrl+shift in Ubuntu 20.04 KDE

Tags: 20.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, kde

I'm new to Linux, I want to use ctrl + switch to change languages, but it's not allowed from those settings. I use KDE.

This is where I tried changing the settings:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The screenshot from your question shows IBus Preferences configuration window.

While really you need KDE Keyboard Configuration. Access it as follows:

1. Open applications menu/dash
2. Find Keyboard *Keyboard Hardware and Layout* or launch using `kcmshell5 kcm_keyboard`
3. Go to Layouts tab, add necessary layouts
4. Go to Advanced tab and set *Switching to another layout* to *Ctrl+Shift*

   > [image: KDE Keyboard Settings]
5. Click *OK*
6. Enjoy.

Note: you may have problems with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+... shortcuts, this problem is fixable by using packages from [my PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Enrbrtx/+archive/ubuntu/xorg-hotkeys).

Comment: That worked, thanks, I thought those settings were for something else before haha